# How to cut cylinder in a bending shape without deformations?

Tags: modeling

First message in blender but after hours trying to find a solution, I need help from you guys!

I would like to draw with 3 lines a sharp curve, in which a cylinder will follow them and be cut at the meeting points without deformation (like a rigid object).
Of course there will be superpositions of the pieces of the cylinder if there is no deformation to take the curve, but this is perfect because I would like to know the shape of this superposition.

Like that I will know how I have to cut the cylinder (so remove littles triangles) to shape it exactly like the curve.

so 1) Do you know a tool to design just lines linked together to design the shape (path is not good because it s not a curve I need, but a sequence of 3 lines changing direction at nods points),
2) I can I do to force the cylinder to take the shape of the 3 successive lines and tell me the superpositions parts?

Thank you so much!!!

[image: Remove the ill bone and shape a cylinder piece by piece]
[image: The cylinder : remove triangles to shape it exactly in the shape you want]

Answer (score 1):

To get straight lines using the **bezier curve** you can set a **low** amount of **resolution**:

[image]

[image]

(You could even draw the path as a mesh and than convert to a curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get a similar result.)

Than assign as a "Bevel Object" of the curve the wanted profile section.

[image]

To get the individuals cylinders, you can enter in the curve edit mode, select a pair of adiacent vertex and than **separate** them from the curve object with the <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut. Repeat the process for every couple of vertex of each segment.

[image]

[image]

Now that we have **individuals cylinders** that follows the given **segments** of the path, we should convert them to mesh to operate with **Boolean Modifiers** to get the shape of superposition parts (intersection) and the cut shape (difference).

[image] [image]

While in edit mode you can translate the cap faces along their normal to extend the cylinder to the chosen lenght.

[image]

---

If you can use not only rect cylinders but also [oblique cylinders](http://www.mathopenref.com/cylinderoblique.html) to avoid the part in which you have to bool the parts (can be tricky), you can **convert th curve to mesh** before splitting and than **Rip** (<kbd>V</kbd>) the edge ring on the path angles and than slide it slightly.

[image]