# How modeling a complex object into a shape draw by a sharp line?

Tags: modeling

After hours of tutorials, and the first help of Carlo, I'm looking in a way to force an object, like a "bone" (so not exactly a regular cylindre, with a lot of meshs) to shape itself into a sharpe path of 3 or 4 points (path converting in meshs after alt+C, let s call it "a guide"). 
So the idea is to use this guide like a tool to shape the bone object linked and without deformation (like a solid object) as you can see :

[image]

So to begin with... it s difficult : because it s not a bezier item, it s a complexe cylindre. So I can t use "bevel object"  with an object like that...

After this step, I think there are two possibility to see the problem :

1) You can superpose pieces of the bone if they split on an exact point of the guide (so exactly on the point between two lines). I will know how I have to "cut the bone" (so remove littles triangles) to shape it exactly like the guide (with boolean union modifier for exemple!), but like it s an object more like a triangle long bone object, one of its faces is large and have to be always at the bottom part of the modeling...

So 2) No superpositions but a complexe serie of movements (spin, translation,..) of the pieces on after the other to touch themselves in a "solid" mode, to force the large face to be always at the bottom... 
Like that the little triangles removed will be much more smaller +++

[image]

I know it s very difficult to have the 2) option. S I think the first one with boolean modifier will be more than enought (but if you have an idea of course..).

Thank you so much for your time and help in this difficult modeling!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think i found something, not really easy.

Create an armature, enter Edit mode, make it flat and subdivide the bone (<kbd>W</kbd>, subdivide and choose the number)
[image: armature]

In pose mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), rotate and scale your bones to fit the shape you need
[image: pose]

Select all your bones and store the pose in the pose library, we'll use it later. Now cancel the rotation of your bones and apply the pose as the rest pose.
[image: pose store apply]

Now add a cube, in edit mode, move the faces to fit the armature and add an edge loops for each bone joint. back in object mode, parent the mesh to the armature (select mesh 1st then armature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, choose automatic weights)
[image: add cube]

Now select your bone object (the thing that you'll cut) duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, move the duplicate to the armature and parent it to the 1st bone (select the mesh then the bone, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, choose bone). Do as much duplicates as you have bones and parent them the same way.
[image: parent bones to bones]

Now select all your bones (armature) and apply the pose your stored earlier and clear the scale (menu or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
[image: pose]

If the cube mesh needs it, correct the vertex groups. This should be simple with a lowpoly mesh and few bones.
[image: VGroup weight]

Now apply the armature modifier on the cube and in edit mode separate the elements (select and <kbd>P</kbd>). Add faces to close them.
[image: separate bool]

Now you have 3 cubes usable as booleans to cut the 3 bone objects where you need. You can easily move the bone objects along their local coordinates for minor adjustments.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!! It s working very nicely! amazing idea to combine the cubs with the armature first to use them like boolean modifiers after that! I can complete my work thank to you Bithur. You are the best!

Comment: Glad to help :) Think about accepting answers : http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35459/11431